# Animate a linear layout in android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-animation

I am new to android and trying to create an application in native android.

I have a top bar which is 10% height of the whole screen and full width. Initially I want to show the bar when application launch. When user drag the application downwards, need to animate the "top bar" to -10%, so that user can't view. Also when user drag screen upwards then need to animate the "top bar" to 0, ie beginning of the screen ( normal position ).

So I have my layout like this

```
<relativelayout>
<linearLayout>
// Top bar content here 
<linearLayout>


<linearLayout>

// With list items, etc

</linearLayout>


</relativelayout>
```

I am stuck on that animation part. How to get the events and do the animation.

Please give me a hint.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not very sure about how what you need what you need for. But its very similar to the IMMERSIVE Mode in android.

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

Answer (score 0):

You could create an onTouch() method where the View is the whole screen. Specify what you want the top bar to do depending on the touch motion. Here's some code to start:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent evt) {
    switch(evt.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // your code that makes it disappear
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // your code that makes it reappear
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In your xml, add ids to your layout.

```
<LinearLayout 
 android:id="my_layout"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent">
   <TextView
    android:id="topbar"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
   <ListView
    android:id="list"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="9">
</LinearLayout>
```

The ids will be what you call upon in your onTouch() method to change the layout weight, or percentage of the top bar, from 1 to 0 and vice versa at your discretion.

Look into [the first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12298927/3116237) for an algorithm for figuring out whether the touch event scrolled up or down.

Comment: hi chips thanks for your comment. but can you please help me how to animate that linearLayout to -10% ?

Comment: Now that I'm looking at your xml code, I'm not sure if this is the best approach to your problem. Based on what you have, I'd recommend having a single layout (relative or linear) and use TextView and ListView for the various elements on your page.